# Adjusted p-value for conducting 7 linear regression models?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear, bonferroni

I am looking at factors that are associated to changes in student's grades over time. My dataset consists of 45 students with Time 1 and Time 2 grades across 7 different subjects as well as characteristics about these students. As you can see in the below sample dataset each student will have 7 different scores. I want to look at factors associated with changes in math scores, english scores, history scores...separately.

I am running 7 different multiple linear regression models (one model for each subject). The outcome for every model is the same (change in subject scores) and the starting IV for each model prior to stepwise selection is the same. I am using a backward stepwise selection to come to the final multivariate for all models. Although for each model different variables show up as significant. All models are using the same dataset. For instance each student has a T1 and T2 score for each subject.

```
student <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
subject <- c("math", "his", "geo", "eng", "art","math", "his", "geo", "eng", "art")
t1_grade <- c(78,54,78,67,72,89,76,80,99,76)
t2_grade <- c(67,60,65,78,81,87,90,67,92,79)
age <- c(18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18,18)
sex <- c("M","M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F","F")

data <- data.frame(student, subject, t1_grade,t2_grade, age,sex)
daya$grade_change <- daya$t2_grade- daya$t1_grade


 student subject t1_grade t2_grade age sex grade_change
1        1    math       78       67  18   M          -11
2        1     his       54       60  18   M            6
3        1     geo       78       65  18   M          -13
4        1     eng       67       78  18   M           11
5        1     art       72       81  18   M            9
6        2    math       89       87  18   F           -2
7        2     his       76       90  18   F           14
8        2     geo       80       67  18   F          -13
9        2     eng       99       92  18   F           -7
10       2     art       76       79  18   F            3
```

1. I assume I have to adjust the p-values for multiple testing. Would my number of tests be 7 because I am running 7 multivariate linear regression models?

2.From my reading, to correct using the Bonferroni method I would divide the 0.05/7 and my new significance level would be 0.007. Is that correct?

3. If I were to use the hochberg correction, how would I go about doing this for all 7 models?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: "I am using a backward stepwise selection" - why?

Comment: My PI mentioned due to smaller sample sizes and the fact that this is more exploratory than hypothesis testing, it would be alright to use it. Would you suggest using a different approach for variable selection?

Comment: Your PI is not correct. We need to know a lot more about your situation, your data, your models & your goals.  What is the study?  Etc.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have added more detail above.

Comment: The backward stepwise selection is also what got my attention. You shouldn't do this unless you're doing doubly robust backward stepwise selection. Doubly robust Lasso selection is generally preferred though. See this article for a very approachable introduction: https://home.uchicago.edu/ourminsky/Variable_Selection.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I have heard of the lasso selection and will look into that instead. Also wondering, if I am running these 7 different linear regression models, should I be reporting adjusted p-values?